# Working with .SUP and .SMTI files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, .smti, .sup

I have just recieved 3.63TB of data for a project area and it is all in .sup and .smti file formats.

Looking up what these extensions are, I see it is a result of a product called SOCET SET (http://www.geospatialexploitationproducts.com/content/socet-set-v56/).

I am working in ArcGIS Desktop and see that support for .sup files has been revoked as of 10.2.

How do I begin to assess the data that I have in ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

The .SMTI files indicate that it was generated with SUMMIT DAT/EM. You can use either SUMMIT DAT/EM or ERDAS Stereo Analyst to view the .sup files. If you right click on the .sup files and open them in a text editor (eg. note pad or textedit), you will see that it has a number of file paths. Make a backup copy of these .sup files before you edit them and then correct the file paths so that they point to where your .tif or .smti files are located. This can be done in batch with an edit replace command in TextEdit. Generally the file structure will have a CAM folder, an L1s folder and a sup folder or the .sup files may be in the L1s folder itself.